# Optimizing a UIScrollView with a lot of subviews

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollView that I am using to simulate a UITableView like interaction because rows are a bit more complex than what UITableView has to offer.  I have 4 UILables a UIImageView and a UIButton for every row.  The end result is a lot of subviews.

Even with only 10 rows,the scroll view that looks fine in the simulator but has a fairly low frame rate on the iPhone 4. This is a resource consumption issue for sure.

Is there a way to optimize the redraw durring scrolling like double buffering?

If not is there another way to get customizable UITableview functionality?

thanks

Comment: I'll echo what's implicit in the answers below. If your view is "nearly" a table view (in that it's a vertically scrolling list), you can almost certainly do what you need with UITableView. You can have absolutely arbitrary cells in the table view with as much complexity as you need. Don't reinvent the wheel here unless you really have to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does every View have 4xUILabels, a UIImageView and a UIButton?

I would create a nib file with a custom UITableViewCell (You can make those as complex as you want), then you can reuse the cells to help with your performance.

Information on how to do this is here: 
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW1

Comment: If scrolling performance is an issue, you shouldn't create a Cell with multiple subviews like that. Use flat view hierarchy and customize your drawing of the cell with method such as drawString... Also, make your cell view/subviews opaque if possible. Look at some of the sample code from Apple, they also use custom drawing instead of Nib file to avoid the use of subviews.

Answer (score 1):

I think you probably want to create a custom subclass of a UITableViewCell as the UITableView will handle all the redrawing for you. In a custom UITableViewCell you can add as many subviews as you like.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html.

UITableViews are subclasses of UIScrollView (or at least conform to their behavior), but you really want to let the iPhone handle the selective drawing/cell reuse for you that the UITableView provides.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `UITableView` if it does everything you need.

However if your tableview cells are really complicated, or you want to enable paging on the scrollview, you should take a look at the `PageContol` sample code that Apple provides. In a nutshell, you watch for movement in `scrollViewDidScroll:` and load new "pages" just before they become visible. This method works very well in practice for arbitrarily long lists of pages.